# Installing FFmpeg in ubuntu server which file to run for installing ffmpeg from downloaded package

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have downloaded ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.org to manipulate multimedia data using php codeigniter  and i have got a package with bunch of libraries inside.
I want to run the ffmpeg in ubuntu server but i don't know which file (.exec file) to run from that package.please anyone who could help me figure out which file to Execute to use ffmpeg.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of editing an old one so it is completely different. Especially one that has received an answer and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Install the yasm assembler

```
sudo apt-get install yasm
```

Configure the build. You can add your own options here.

```
./configure
```

Build and install.

```
make -j9
sudo make install
```

Find out more https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

EDIT: I'm not familiar with ffmpeg and php because I mainly use the shared libraries with my own C++ code. However, there is some information about using it from web pages here -> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP

Comment: Thanks WLGfx i will look into that. if you give me bit of hint on how to use its commands on php code-igniter because i am using commands like exec('ffmpeg -i $videsrc') it returns null

Comment: Updated my answer with a link...

Comment: Thanks man,that's helpful.